# Clone eloquent models for different queries

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

**Sorry for modifying this question (to all those who have answered here). The question was in fact wrong.**

```
$query = User::find(1)->books();  //books() is "return $this->hasMany('Book');"

$query_for_counting_history_books = clone $query;
$query_for_counting_geography_books = clone $query;

$number_of_history_books = $query_for_counting_history_books->where('type', '=', 'history')->count();
$number_of_geography_books = $query_for_counting_geography_books->where('type', '=', 'geography')->count();

$books = $query->paginate(10);
```

I want $books to be queried as:

> SELECT * FROM books WHERE user_id=1 limit 10;

But its output is:

> SELECT * FROM books WHERE user_id=1 and type="history" and type="geography"
>   limit 10;

- Am I missing something about **Clone** here?
- What should be done for this solution?

Comment: It works as expected for me. Can you check if your `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` has the `__clone()` method implemented?

Comment: @Demodave No, absolutely not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $query is instance of HasMany, So the cloning should be done as:

> $query_for_counting_history_books = clone $query->getQuery();
>
> $query_for_counting_geography_books = clone $query->getQuery();

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.html#method_getQuery

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why your `clone()` is not working - but try this:

```
$query = User::where('confirmed', '=', '1');
$query_for_counting_male = $query->replicate();
$query_for_counting_female = $query->replicate();
```

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_replicate

Comment: Replicate was perfect for what I wanted. Clone everything except the primary key. Thanks!